# What is the general method for including plugins installed via Bower?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower-install

Imagine I've just used `bower install angular-date-range-picker` to install a plugin I want in the root directory of my project.

Now typically all of my js files (angular project) are sitting in a folder called js on on the root directory of the project.

Here's where I feel I'm missing something. How do I include my nice new plugin into my project without tracing back through every dependency the bower command installed? I typically include all my scripts on the index.html with  tags. I've copied the plugin js file out of the bower_components folder and into my js folder (which I now feel is wrong).

If this is an acceptable way to link to plugins then should I be linking directly to the bower_components folder and how do I include all of that plugin's dependencies without literally writing a script tag for each one? (And how do I know what it depends on, there are other plugins in that bower_components folder for instance).

Apologies if this question doesn't make any sense, I'm obviously missing some very important workflow knowledge and I don't know how to phrase the question to find want I want with Google.

Comment: [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.org/package/main-bower-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be writing a script tag for each one. In most cases, check the corresponding github repo to see what dependency libraries are needed. In addition to this, a hint to see what file you should be referencing in your script tag will have an extension of `.min`. `.min` is a minified version of the library that removes whitespace and replaces large variable names.

Once your application is ready for production, there are a couple things you can do.

You may want to move to a Content Delivery Network (CDN) instead of referencing your files locally. The advantage of this is you'll have a reliable host hosting your library files.

Another option is to use either Grunt or Gulp, which has the ability to combine all of your dependancy files into one file. The advantage of this is having a much quicker load time of loading one file instead of multiple.

[Content Delivery Network - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

[Grunt - Homepage](http://gruntjs.com/)

[Gulp - Homepage](http://gulpjs.com/)

Comment: or you can use gulp/grunt to concat all 3rd party/vendor files and include all in one.

Comment: Okay, so I was on the right track then, you literally do have to figure out what dependencies are required by a plugin (docs are rarely forthcoming with this sort of information I find) and link to each in turn. I like the concatenation idea. I suppose that makes things much easier.

Comment: @lorless yeah main bower files concat to one file so it automagically arrange them in the right order for you as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's configured something like this:

```
<!-- build:js ${contextRoot}/app/assets/scripts/modules.min.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

to include script into index.html. Then during build process some grunt/gulp (grunt-usemin, for example) plugins can replace the entire section between `<!-- build: -->` comments with minified version of the files.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [grunt-injector](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-injector), it's been specially made for that and can be used to automatically inject bower dependencies into your `index.html`, as well as your other js/css files (you will need the [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) dependency).

You will no longer have to worry about your files injection.